# Complex conditional rails 3 activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Below is the current code in Package.rb

```
def self.available
  joins(:deals).where(:available_for_purchase => true).uniq
end
```

Now I want more conditions on packages, here conditions are::

```
:duration != nil
:expiration_date > Date.today
```

- Both :duration and :expiration date should not be present, I mean one
  of them must be null,
- Both can not be null as well.
- return packages which satisfy all conditions above

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally got the query, and here is the outcome

```
def available
    joins(:deals).where("available_for_purchase=?
            AND(
               (expiration_date IS NOT NULL AND expiration_date > ? AND duration IS NULL)
                OR (duration IS NOT NULL AND expiration_date IS NULL)
         ) ",true,Date.today).group(:id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question right, can you try this:

```
def self.available
  joins(:deals).where("available_for_purchase = ? AND duration NOT ? AND expiration_date > ?",
      true,
      nil,
      Date.today
  ).uniq
end
```

Comment: yes, you understood it correctly but not the conditions, 
skip package if Both :duration and :expiration is set, same if both of them are nil

Comment: So you mean sth. like: `... AND ((duration = NULL AND expiration_date > ?) OR (duration > ? AND expiration_date = NULL)) AND duration NOT expiration_date`